# cron job generated by whenever/capistrano for a Sinatra app sets the wrong environment variable

Tags: ruby, cron, sinatra, whenever

I am using the whenever gem in a Sinatra app to create a cron job. I am using whenever/capistrano so that the job is created/updated on deploy. This is the whenever setup of my deploy script:

```
require 'whenever/capistrano'
set :environment_variable, 'RACK_ENV'
set :whenever_roles,        ->{ :app }
set :whenever_command,      ->{ [:bundle, :exec, :whenever] }
set :whenever_command_environment_variables, ->{ { rack_env: fetch(:whenever_environment), rails_env: nil } }
set :whenever_identifier,   ->{ "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:stage)}" }
set :whenever_environment,  ->{ fetch :rack_env, fetch(:stage, "production") }
set :whenever_variables,    ->{ "environment=#{fetch :whenever_environment}" }
set :whenever_update_flags, ->{ "--update-crontab #{fetch :whenever_identifier} --set #{fetch :whenever_variables}" }
set :whenever_clear_flags,  ->{ "--clear-crontab #{fetch :whenever_identifier}" }
```

When I deploy, I can see that capistrano runs the crontab update and it seems like the proper environment variable is going to be used:

```
INFO [8b4f49a6] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec whenever --update-crontab sidekiq-monitor-ua_staging --set environment=staging --roles=app as deploy@10.0.254.37
DEBUG [8b4f49a6] Command: cd /var/www/sidekiq-monitor-ua/releases/20160725170122 && ( RACK_ENV=staging RAILS_ENV= ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec whenever --update-crontab sidekiq-monitor-ua_staging --set environment=staging --roles=app )
DEBUG [8b4f49a6]        [write] crontab file updated
```

However, this is what I get in the crontab (this was generated deploying to my staging environment):

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: sidekiq-monitor-ua_staging
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/sidekiq-monitor-ua/releases/20160725170122 && RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake log_sidekiq_status --silent >> /dev/null 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: sidekiq-monitor-ua_staging
```

Consequently, when the crontab runs the rake task, RACK_ENV is not set and the code doesn't run properly because it defaults to the development environment.

I am either missing something or have something misconfigured. I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

The environment_variable mentioned in whenever github README about job types: https://github.com/javan/whenever#define-your-own-job-types

The default rake job here

> job_type :rake,    "cd :path && :environment_variable=:environment bundle exec rake :task --silent :output"
>   job_type :runner,  "cd :path && bin/rails runner -e :environment ':task' :output"
>
> :environment_variable will default to 'RAILS_ENV'

You can try this below.

```
require 'whenever/capistrano'
set :environment_variable, 'RACK_ENV'
set :whenever_roles,        ->{ :app }
set :whenever_command,      ->{ [:bundle, :exec, :whenever] }
set :whenever_command_environment_variables, ->{ {} }
set :whenever_identifier,   ->{ "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:stage)}" }
set :whenever_environment,  ->{ fetch :rack_env, fetch(:stage, "production") }
set :whenever_variables,    ->{ "'environment=#{fetch :whenever_environment}&environment_variable=RACK_ENV'" }
set :whenever_update_flags, ->{ "--update-crontab #{fetch :whenever_identifier} --set #{fetch :whenever_variables}" }
set :whenever_clear_flags,  ->{ "--clear-crontab #{fetch :whenever_identifier}" }
```